# Concept of homogeneous inequalities

Tags: inequality

$a, b, c>0$, prove  that, $$\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+8bc}}\geq 1$$

In this question, how can we assume that $a+b+c=1$. How is this inequality homogeneous?

Comment: By my count, you might have three questions here.  Are you just asking why we may assume, without loss of generality, that $a+b+c=1$?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the numerator and denominator is of the same degree (degree 1).

For example, suppose that $a+b+c = M.$ Now define the variables $$a' = a/M, b' = b/M, c' = c/M.$$

Now notice that $$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + 8bc}} = \frac{a/M}{\sqrt{(a/M)^2 + 8(b/M)(c/M)}} = \frac{a'}{\sqrt{a'^2 + 8b'c'}}.$$ The point here is that the expression doesn't depend on how you scale the variables (this worked out because the numerator and demoniator are both of degree 1, so when you do the scaling, it cancels out). Therefore, the inequality will be the exact same regardless of what $M$ is, so you might as well assume (i.e., you can assume without loss of generality), that $M=1$.